# Kendo error when upgrading Angular to 6.1.3

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-ui-angular2

I upgraded Angular to version 6.1.3 and now get this error when trying to start the application. Any ideas how to fix this? I tried to reinstall Kendo international but the error persists.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was fixed in the latest version of Kendo for Angular